# flot: zero values are displayed on the axis

Tags: flot

One of my line charts contain values in the range 0..11.5

flot is using yaxis with 0..12

the problem: value 0 is drawn on the axis (see attached image)

Is there a way to tell flot to add a small margin, e.g. use 0.5 margin?
or - Is there a way to get the min and max values, so I manually can set xmin and xmax?

[image: flot with zero values on the axis]

Answer (score 0):

There is the `autoscaleMargin` [option for the axis](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) which does what you want. Or you can set `min` and `max` values for the axis manually.

The default for `autoscaleMargin` on the y-axis is `0.02` (you can see that the points are not completely on the axis but slighty above). Increase this to your liking.

Comment: The `autoscaleMargin` option [doesn't seem to work sometimes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flot-graphs/J0hpWkuh4SA), so you might have to calculate your `min` and `max` values manually.

Comment: @Raidri, Using autoscaleMargin did not help. just to verify that I used it correct: 1. added to yAxis option. 2. changed to 0.5, 5, none helped. in what units is it measured? maybe I have the same case as @ mechenbier mentioned, zero multiply by any number is still zero ?!